# How to select a shipping box for a particular product based on quantity using Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have two shipping rules for a particular product.

Case 1. (Shipping box)

```
Quantity: 1-12
Width: 6
Height: 6
Length: 8.75
Weight: 3
```

Case 2. (Shipping box)

```
Quantity: 13-24
Width: 8
Height: 6.5
Length: 11.25
Weight: 4
```

When a user purchases this particular product, if the quantity below 12, use Case 1 shipping dimensions. If greater than 12, use Case 2.

Anyone can point out how to achieve this? I'm using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) with [Commerce FedEx](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fedex) as shipping service.

There's a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trLydGpimD4) on how to achieve something like this but it uses flat rate and not any shipping box dimensions.

Comment: Do you have to use FedEx module. Seems like it would be easy to set up with flat rate.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens only 1 get triggered, if the quantity is < 12, use 1st case shipping dimensions, if more than 12, use 2nd case dimensions

Comment: @googletorp the requirement is to use FedEx module, I already included a link for flat rate tutorial

Comment: @slashsharp : ok, that part (in your last comment) I understand, but what is the problem with that, and how would you want it to work? Also: (a) I find the 1-24 for "case 2" bizarre: shouldn't that be like "13-24"? (b) please include your exported rules as I asked in my prior comment (your question seems really confusing to me, posting those rules may help (c) is "2 case" the same as "case 2", if so please be consistent.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated my question. I don't have any rules configured yet as I don't know how. The only thing I have setup are one product with default shipping dimension (Case 1 shipping width/height/weight) and two shipping boxes (using Drupal Commerce box). How am I going to change shipping dimensions (width/height/weight) when user purchase this product if the quantity is more than 12?

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Commerce Box](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_box) module, for which only a DEV version exists, you can create ***Commerce Box*** entities, but that's about it. E.g. it does not add any specific [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Actions you can use to select the appropriate shipping box, such as based on product items and/or quantities.

However, there is an inspiring issue for the [Commerce Fedex](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fedex) module, titled "[Allow altering of default package dimensions](https://www.drupal.org/node/2267831)". And [comment nr 17](https://www.drupal.org/node/2267831#comment-11581399) of that issue contains an interesting patch which allows for package dimensions alterations.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up editing the module itself. For those who face the same challenges, the file is commerce_fedex_soap_client.inc and the function is _commerce_fedex_get_package_items